# How to transform this HttpPost into an Url

Tags: android, url, http-post

I have the following code that I would like to transform into a simple single URL so that (possibly) I can use Picasso for downloading images:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.GET_OTHER_PROFILE_PICTURE_URL);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
UrlEncodedFormEntity form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
httppost.setEntity(form);
```

Comment: It's a post, it cannot be converted into a simple url.

Comment: On the server side it declares whether you are using a get or a post. Technically if it is listening for both you could turn it into something like <url>?<entry.getKey>=<entry.getValue>. But as he says only works if the server accepts it.

Comment: @Jackie your proposed solution worked perfectly! If you want to post an answer I would gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a GET requests the parameters can be declared in the url like

```
<url>?<entry.getKey>=<entry.getValue>
```

The same parameters (as key value pairs separated by a colon) are passed to a POST request through the body.